# visual studio application stopped working on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have made an application in visual studio 2010 on a windows xp computer. When I compile the release version and run it on a windows xp computer, it runs fine. 
When I on the other hand try to run it on windows 7 I get the "This program has stopped working" error message. Running the application in compatibility mode doesn't change anything. Can someone tell me what I can try to do?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to debug it? what is the exact exception message?

Comment: I have just compiled the release version and copied the bin/release folder to another computer with windows 7 and tried to run the .exe . I then just get a windows message saying "this program is not working" and I can only stop running it. How can I see the error log of this. There is no visual studio on the windows 7 machine. Can I add a windows 7 platform to the visual studio compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provide, it might be a windows 7 vs xp problem or that you don't find any resource that you are looking for. If I were you I would:

- Get sure that app was compiled by any cpu
- Check windows error log to see if there is any message
- Run app as administrator
- Use error handling (try/catch) to see exceptions by showing them in UI or logging to a text file.

EDITED: TRY-CATCH example

```
Try
  //CODE
Catch ex As Exception
 Dim writer As New StreamWriter("C:\MyLog.log", True, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
 writer.WriteLine(ex.Message)
 writer.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: I have just compiled the release version and copied the bin/release folder to another computer with windows 7 and tried to run the .exe . I then just get a windows message saying "this program is not working" and I can only stop running it. How can I see the error log of this. There is no visual studio on the windows 7 machine. Can I add a windows 7 platform to the visual studio compiler?

Comment: Multiple reasons can stop it from work (different CPU optimization, 64 vs 32 bits, missing resources, etc.) What you need mainly is to have access to exception to be able to identify the source of the problem. Did you look at windows logs? Does you code contains a TRY/CATCH at the upper level?

Comment: The best thing you can do is surround main method with try/catch and write exception message and if exists, inner exception message to a log.txt file. With the information you will be able to fix the problem.

Comment: I have written the program in vb.net (forms application). Do I put the try catch block around the startup class or?

Comment: Yes. And in Catch you can put code to write ex.message to a file. I have edited answer to put you an example

Comment: So the try catch is now around the public sub new() of the startup class. Will this also show me errormessages when the references are not good?

Comment: Thanks it works now. There was an accesibility problem with some of the external files.

Comment: Congrats! You should always have some sort of logging to avoid this problems. As minimum use this. If you have time use log4net framework that gives you more control like the ability to log in file/db/error logger...

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this issue also.  As my solution was completely different, I thought I would share just in case someone else found it relevant.

My problem was that in my project references I had two references to Adobe Acrobat DLL files.  I was getting the error on my new client machine because it didn't have Adobe Reader installed (which installs the DLL's that my project references).  Once I installed Adobe Reader, my program installed properly.

The interesting part of debugging this is that no TRY/CATCH block would have caught it.  Apparently the check for reference happens before the code is run.  You literally just get the generic message "ProgramName has stopped working".

Just FYI...